# Azure Sphere OS version updated to wrong version and I cannot deploy applications anymore

Tags: azure, azure-sphere

I was running the Azure Sphere Blink1 project template without a problem, both with local debugging and deploying the application.

But then my Avnet Azure Sphere OS updated from 19.10 to 19.11.

But after that I wasn't able to deploy the application over the air, local debugging is still ok.

```
azsphere device show-deployment-status

Your device is running Azure Sphere OS version 19.11.
The Azure Sphere Security Service is targeting this device with Azure Sphere OS version 19.10.
warn: Your device is running an older Azure Sphere OS version (19.11). It has not yet started receiving the available update to version 19.10.
warn: Your device is connected to Wi-Fi. If the over-the-air update does not begin, reset your device and try again.
Go to aka.ms/AzureSphereUpgradeGuidance for further advice and support.
```

So I reset, waited a while, tried a few more resets, still wasn't able to deploy.
I tried the recover command which went well and got my sphere to 19.10 again.

```
azsphere device recover
. . .
Device recovered successfully.
```

But still I am not able to deploy the sample Blink1 template image over the air.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding back WiFi settings allowed over the air deployments.

```
azsphere device wifi add --ssid . . .
```

Should have checked that earlier :)

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is resolved. Please mark your response as answer so that others who checks this issue can be benefited as well.